# Set form field placeholder attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, textfield, placeholder

I am trying to set the placeholder attribute for a form which I do not have access to. I would like to use the name of the field to populate this. Does anyone know of a way to do this using javascript.

This is the html for the form field:

`<input type="text" onchange="checkdep(this);" onblur="validatefield(this);" value="" name="First Name" class="formTextfield" id="First_Name">`

I am able to do this using getElementById but would like something which works for all the fields in the form without having to set it individually for each field.

http://jsfiddle.net/XF6wT/5/

Thanks

Comment: If there is only one form in the page, you can get it using the [*forms*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-forms) collection: `document.forms[0]`. You can then iterate over all the controls in the form using its [*elements*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-form-elements) collection. You can then work out which are input elements that you wish to add a placeholder to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some thing like this

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
   inputs[index].setAttribute('placeholder', inputs[index].getAttribute("name"));
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XF6wT/8/)

If you need to constrain it into a form try

```
var inputs = document.forms["form_name"].getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Comment: Thanks, this did just what I asked for. I have instead gone for the solution suggested here as it deals with some of the usability issues that arise http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/float-label-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
document.getElementById("First_Name").setAttribute('placeholder', document.getElementById("First_Name").getAttribute("name"));
```

do you need this ... I am not sure..

check this:

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/XF6wT/6/

If you want for all tags of form then you can find all tags of form and add this via for loop.

Comment: Thanks, but this still requires me to name each specific element. If possible I'd like something which applies to every input in the form.

http://jsfiddle.net/XF6wT/7/